# SQL query : aggregating records having a timestamped field, where fields timestamp falls in same time unit (sec, min, hour..)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database table `customers` that records among others the arrival time of clients for a one month data. So, the `customers` table contains among other a column named `arrival_time`  . (e.g., arrival_time = 12/1/2020  12:01:39 AM, arrival_time = 12/1/2020  12:01:34 AM etc…)
Is it possible to  design/write an SQL query that returns the numbers of customers that arrived each second (or say, min, hour...) in this  this one month data.

Thank you.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags. Please tag one database only.

Comment: Date and time handling varies greatly between makes and versions of RDBMS. ☹️  It's hard to help without knowing which one you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using PostgreSQL you can use `DATE_TRUNC()`. For example:

```
select
  date_trunc('minute', arrival_time) as at,
  count(distinct customer_id) as cnt
from t
group by date_trunc('minute', arrival_time)
```

You can change `'minute'` for `'day'`, `'week'`,  `'second'`, etc. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC